# Random.Choice always the same result

Tags: python, random, pygame-mixer

Some pretext that's maybe useful idk. I use mixer and am trying to do a random music choice but the `random.choice` always take the last one (song 5). This is my code

```
if Mamp=='1':
vad=input("[1] Bakground music")
#Mixer shit
mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.get_init
if vad=='1':
    commands=[mixer.music.load("song1.mp3"), mixer.music.load("song2.mp3"),mixer.music.load("song3.mp3"),mixer.music.load("song4.mp3"),mixer.music.load("song5.mp3")]
    current_command=random.choice(commands)
    current_command
    mixer.music.play(0)
```

I looked at many answers for the same problem but all wer're just fixing thier (the uploader's) code and uploaded it so I couldn't use it for my code. And since i'm trying to learn python it would be great if you could also explain what went wrong?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `mixer.music.load`? It seems as though you expect that picking a random value from `commands` will affect which song is played. Why? Did you try to check what `commands` contains? (After reading the documentation, do you understand why?) Aside: `current_command` doesn't do anything by itself; this is in a script, so you can't see the value that way - if you want a script to display something, you have to do that explicitly, for example using `print`. Also, `pygame.mixer.get_init` is a *function*, and this code does *not* call it.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please re-read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure you understand how to make the code appear with the same indentation as you actually have, since indentation is crucial in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
commands=[mixer.music.load("song1.mp3"), ...]
current_command=random.choice(commands)
current_command
```

You're doing this part all wrong.

It seems like you want to make a list of commands to be executed *later*, but that's not what you're actually doing.  The `load()` commands are *actually executed* when the `commands` list is created.
And because `song5.mp3` is the last one, it gives the appearance of being "picked" every time.

Try it this way instead:

```
songs = ["song1.mp3", "song2.mp3", "song3.mp3", "song4.mp3", "song5.mp3"]
song = random.choice(songs)
mixer.music.load(song)
```

Comment: I think it's possible that OP didn't understand that multiple `mixer.music.load` calls *can't* just be done ahead of time. Given that a separate `.play` call is required in order to actually hear the music, it would seem like a reasonable expectation.